# SQL what is wrong with the syntax here?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

What is wrong with the syntax in this function? I am getting the following errors:

```
        ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[udf_ReportingLevelStructure2] 
(   
    @CompanyID INT
)
RETURNS @result TABLE 
( 
CompanyName VARCHAR(300), 
[rl_Index] INT, 
[rl_Addr1] VARCHAR(MAX), 
[rl_Addr2] VARCHAR(MAX), 
[rl_DisplayName] VARCHAR(MAX) 
)
AS  
BEGIN 


DECLARE @tmp1 TABLE
(
CompanyName VARCHAR(300),
[rl_Index] INT,
[rl_Addr1] VARCHAR(MAX),
[rl_Addr2] VARCHAR(MAX),
[rl_DisplayName] VARCHAR(MAX)
);
DECLARE @tmp2 TABLE
(
[CompanyName] VARCHAR(300),
[rl_Index] INT,
[rl_Addr1] VARCHAR(MAX),
[rl_Addr2] VARCHAR(MAX),
[rl_DisplayName] VARCHAR(MAX)
)

INSERT INTO @tmp1([CompanyName],[rl_Index],[rl_Addr1],[rl_Addr2],[rl_DisplayName])
(SELECT
        rl0.[rl_Name] AS [CompanyName] 
        ,rl_Index =
        CASE
            WHEN rl9.[rl_Name] IS NOT NULL THEN rl9.[rl_Index]
            WHEN rl8.[rl_Name] IS NOT NULL THEN rl8.[rl_Index]
            WHEN rl7.[rl_Name] IS NOT NULL THEN rl7.[rl_Index]
            WHEN rl6.[rl_Name] IS NOT NULL THEN rl6.[rl_Index]
            WHEN rl5.[rl_Name] IS NOT NULL THEN rl5.[rl_Index]
            WHEN rl4.[rl_Name] IS NOT NULL THEN rl4.[rl_Index]
            WHEN rl3.[rl_Name] IS NOT NULL THEN rl3.[rl_Index]
            WHEN rl2.[rl_Name] IS NOT NULL THEN rl2.[rl_Index]
            WHEN rl1.[rl_Name] IS NOT NULL THEN rl1.[rl_Index]
        END 
        ,rl_Addr1 =
        CASE
            WHEN rl9.[rl_Name] IS NOT NULL THEN rl9.[rl_Addr1]
            WHEN rl8.[rl_Name] IS NOT NULL THEN rl8.[rl_Addr1]
            WHEN rl7.[rl_Name] IS NOT NULL THEN rl7.[rl_Addr1]
            WHEN rl6.[rl_Name] IS NOT NULL THEN rl6.[rl_Addr1]
            WHEN rl5.[rl_Name] IS NOT NULL THEN rl5.[rl_Addr1]
            WHEN rl4.[rl_Name]IS NOT NULL THEN rl4.[rl_Addr1]
            WHEN rl3.[rl_Name] IS NOT NULL THEN rl3.[rl_Addr1]
            WHEN rl2.[rl_Name] IS NOT NULL THEN rl2.[rl_Addr1]
            WHEN rl1.[rl_Name] IS NOT NULL THEN rl1.[rl_Addr1]
        END
        ,rl_Addr2 =
        CASE
            WHEN rl9.[rl_Name] IS NOT NULL THEN rl9.[rl_Addr2]
            WHEN rl8.[rl_Name] IS NOT NULL THEN rl8.[rl_Addr2]
            WHEN rl7.[rl_Name] IS NOT NULL THEN rl7.[rl_Addr2]
            WHEN rl6.[rl_Name] IS NOT NULL THEN rl6.[rl_Addr2]
            WHEN rl5.[rl_Name] IS NOT NULL THEN rl5.[rl_Addr2]
            WHEN rl4.[rl_Name] IS NOT NULL THEN rl4.[rl_Addr2]
            WHEN rl3.[rl_Name] IS NOT NULL THEN rl3.[rl_Addr2]
            WHEN rl2.[rl_Name] IS NOT NULL THEN rl2.[rl_Addr2]
            WHEN rl1.[rl_Name]IS NOT NULL THEN rl1.[rl_Addr2]
        END
        ,CASE
            WHEN rl9.[rl_Name] IS NOT NULL THEN rl1.[rl_Name]+'> '+rl2.[rl_Name]+'> '+rl3.[rl_Name]+'> '+rl4.[rl_Name]+'> '+ rl5.[rl_Name]+'> '+ rl6.[rl_Name]+'> '+rl7.[rl_Name]+'> '+ rl8.[rl_Name]+'> '+ rl9.[rl_Name]
            WHEN rl8.[rl_Name] IS NOT NULL THEN rl1.[rl_Name]+'> '+rl2.[rl_Name]+'> '+rl3.[rl_Name]+'> '+rl4.[rl_Name]+'> '+ rl5.[rl_Name]+'> '+ rl6.[rl_Name]+'> '+rl7.[rl_Name]+'> '+ rl8.[rl_Name]
            WHEN rl7.[rl_Name] IS NOT NULL THEN rl1.[rl_Name]+'> '+rl2.[rl_Name]+'> '+rl3.[rl_Name]+'> '+rl4.[rl_Name]+'> '+ rl5.[rl_Name]+'> '+ rl6.[rl_Name]+'> '+rl7.[rl_Name]
            WHEN rl6.[rl_Name] IS NOT NULL THEN rl1.[rl_Name]+'> '+rl2.[rl_Name]+'> '+rl3.[rl_Name]+'> '+rl4.[rl_Name]+'> '+ rl5.[rl_Name]+'> '+ rl6.[rl_Name]
            WHEN rl5.[rl_Name] IS NOT NULL THEN rl1.[rl_Name]+'> '+rl2.[rl_Name]+'> '+rl3.[rl_Name]+'> '+rl4.[rl_Name]+'> '+ rl5.[rl_Name]
            WHEN rl4.[rl_Name] IS NOT NULL THEN rl1.[rl_Name]+'> '+rl2.[rl_Name]+'> '+rl3.[rl_Name]+'> '+rl4.[rl_Name]
            WHEN rl3.[rl_Name] IS NOT NULL THEN rl1.[rl_Name]+'> '+rl2.[rl_Name]+'> '+rl3.[rl_Name]
            WHEN rl2.[rl_Name] IS NOT NULL THEN rl1.[rl_Name]+'> '+rl2.[rl_Name] 
            WHEN rl1.[rl_Name] IS NOT NULL THEN rl1.[rl_Name] 
        END AS [rl_DisplayName]

    FROM
        dbo.[ReportingLevels] rl0

        LEFT JOIN ReportingLevels rl1
            ON (rl1.[rl_CompanyID] = @CompanyID
            AND rl1.[rl_Indent1] <> 0 
            AND rl1.[rl_Indent2] = 0)

        LEFT JOIN ReportingLevels rl2
            ON (rl2.[rl_CompanyID] = @CompanyID
            AND rl2.[rl_Indent1] = rl1.[rl_Indent1]
            AND rl2.[rl_Indent2] <> 0
            AND rl2.[rl_Indent3] = 0)

        LEFT JOIN ReportingLevels rl3
            ON (rl3.[rl_CompanyID] = @CompanyID
            AND rl3.[rl_Indent2] = rl2.[rl_Indent2]
            AND rl3.[rl_Indent1] = rl2.[rl_Indent1]
            AND rl3.[rl_Indent3] <> 0
            AND rl3.[rl_Indent4] = 0)

        LEFT JOIN ReportingLevels rl4
            ON (rl4.[rl_CompanyID] = @CompanyID
            AND rl4.[rl_Indent3]= rl3.[rl_Indent3]
            AND rl4.[rl_Indent2] = rl3.[rl_Indent2]
            AND rl4.[rl_Indent1] = rl3.[rl_Indent1]
            AND rl4.[rl_Indent4] <> 0
            AND rl4.[rl_Indent5] = 0)

        LEFT JOIN ReportingLevels rl5
            ON (rl5.[rl_CompanyID] = @CompanyID
            AND rl5.[rl_Indent4] = rl4.[rl_Indent4]
            AND rl5.[rl_Indent3] = rl4.[rl_Indent3]
            AND rl5.[rl_Indent2] = rl4.[rl_Indent2]
            AND rl5.[rl_Indent1] = rl4.[rl_Indent1]
            AND rl5.[rl_Indent5] <> 0
            AND rl5.[rl_Indent6]= 0)

        LEFT JOIN ReportingLevels rl6
            ON (rl6.[rl_CompanyID] = @CompanyID
            AND rl6.[rl_Indent5] = rl5.rl_Indent5
            AND rl6.[rl_Indent4] = rl5.rl_Indent4
            AND rl6.[rl_Indent3] = rl5.rl_Indent3
            AND rl6.[rl_Indent2] = rl5.rl_Indent2
            AND rl6.[rl_Indent1] = rl5.rl_Indent1 
            AND rl6.[rl_Indent6] <> 0
            AND rl6.[rl_Indent7] = 0)

        LEFT JOIN ReportingLevels rl7
            ON (rl7.[rl_CompanyID] = @CompanyID
            AND rl7.[rl_Indent6] = rl6.[rl_Indent6]
            AND rl7.[rl_Indent5] = rl6.[rl_Indent5]
            AND rl7.[rl_Indent4] = rl6.[rl_Indent4]
            AND rl7.[rl_Indent3] = rl6.[rl_Indent3]
            AND rl7.[rl_Indent2] = rl6.[rl_Indent2]
            AND rl7.[rl_Indent1] = rl6.[rl_Indent1] 
            AND rl7.[rl_Indent7] <> 0
            AND rl7.[rl_Indent8] = 0)           

        LEFT JOIN ReportingLevels rl8
            ON (rl8.[rl_CompanyID] = @CompanyID
            AND rl8.[rl_Indent7] = rl7.[rl_Indent7]
            AND rl8.[rl_Indent6] = rl7.[rl_Indent6]
            AND rl8.[rl_Indent5] = rl7.[rl_Indent5]
            AND rl8.[rl_Indent4] = rl7.[rl_Indent4]
            AND rl8.[rl_Indent3] = rl7.[rl_Indent3]
            AND rl8.[rl_Indent2] = rl7.[rl_Indent2]
            AND rl8.[rl_Indent1] = rl7.[rl_Indent1] 
            AND rl8.[rl_Indent8]<> 0
            AND rl7.[rl_Indent9] = 0)

        LEFT JOIN ReportingLevels rl9
            ON (rl9.[rl_CompanyID] = @CompanyID
            AND rl9.[rl_Indent8] = rl8.[rl_Indent8]
            AND rl9.[rl_Indent7] = rl8.[rl_Indent7]
            AND rl9.[rl_Indent6] = rl8.[rl_Indent6]
            AND rl9.[rl_Indent5] = rl8.[rl_Indent5]
            AND rl9.[rl_Indent4] = rl8.[rl_Indent4]
            AND rl9.[rl_Indent3] = rl8.[rl_Indent3]
            AND rl9.[rl_Indent2] = rl8.[rl_Indent2]
            AND rl9.[rl_Indent1] = rl8.[rl_Indent1] 
            AND rl9.[rl_Indent9] <> 0
            AND rl9.[rl_Indent10] = 0)

    WHERE
        rl0.[rl_CompanyID] = @CompanyID
        AND rl0.[rl_Indent1] = 0);

INSERT INTO @tmp2([CompanyName],[rl_Index],[rl_Addr1],[rl_Addr2],[rl_DisplayName])
(SELECT DISTINCT
 rl0.[rl_Name] AS [CompanyName] 
,rl1.[rl_Index]
,rl1.[rl_Addr1]
,rl1.[rl_Addr2]
,CASE WHEN (rl1.[rl_indent1] <> 0 AND rl1.[rl_indent2] = 0 AND rl1.[rl_indent3] = 0 AND rl1.[rl_indent4] = 0 AND rl1.[rl_indent5] = 0 AND rl1.[rl_indent6] = 0 AND rl1.[rl_indent7] = 0 AND rl1.[rl_indent8] = 0 AND rl1.[rl_indent9] = 0) THEN rl1.[rl_Name] END AS [rl_DisplayName]

FROM
        [dbo].[ReportingLevels] rl0

        LEFT JOIN ReportingLevels rl1
            ON (rl1.[rl_CompanyID] = @CompanyID
            AND rl1.[rl_Indent1] <> 0 
            AND rl1.[rl_Indent2] = 0)

        LEFT JOIN ReportingLevels rl2
            ON (rl2.[rl_CompanyID] = @CompanyID
            AND rl2.[rl_Indent1] = rl1.[rl_Indent1] 
            AND rl2.[rl_Indent2] <> 0
            AND rl2.[rl_Indent3] = 0)

        LEFT JOIN ReportingLevels rl3
            ON (rl3.[rl_CompanyID] = @CompanyID
            AND rl3.[rl_Indent2] = rl2.[rl_Indent2]
            AND rl3.[rl_Indent1] = rl2.[rl_Indent1]
            AND rl3.[rl_Indent3] <> 0
            AND rl3.[rl_Indent4] = 0)

        LEFT JOIN ReportingLevels rl4
            ON (rl4.[rl_CompanyID] = @CompanyID
            AND rl4.[rl_Indent3] = rl3.[rl_Indent3]
            AND rl4.[rl_Indent2] = rl3.[rl_Indent2]
            AND rl4.[rl_Indent1] = rl3.[rl_Indent1] 
            AND rl4.[rl_Indent4] <> 0
            AND rl4.[rl_Indent5] = 0)

        LEFT JOIN [ReportingLevels] rl5
            ON (rl5.[rl_CompanyID] = @CompanyID
            AND rl5.[rl_Indent4] = rl4.[rl_Indent4]
            AND rl5.[rl_Indent3] = rl4.[rl_Indent3]
            AND rl5.[rl_Indent2] = rl4.[rl_Indent2]
            AND rl5.[rl_Indent1] = rl4.[rl_Indent1] 
            AND rl5.[rl_Indent5] <> 0
            AND rl5.[rl_Indent6] = 0)

        LEFT JOIN ReportingLevels rl6
            ON (rl6.[rl_CompanyID] = @CompanyID
            AND rl6.[rl_Indent5] = rl5.[rl_Indent5]
            AND rl6.[rl_Indent4] = rl5.[rl_Indent4]
            AND rl6.[rl_Indent3] = rl5.[rl_Indent3]
            AND rl6.[rl_Indent2]= rl5.[rl_Indent2]
            AND rl6.[rl_Indent1] = rl5.[rl_Indent1] 
            AND rl6.[rl_Indent6] <> 0
            AND rl6.[rl_Indent7] = 0)

        LEFT JOIN ReportingLevels rl7
            ON (rl7.[rl_CompanyID] = @CompanyID
            AND rl7.[rl_Indent6] = rl6.[rl_Indent6]
            AND rl7.[rl_Indent5] = rl6.[rl_Indent5]
            AND rl7.[rl_Indent4] = rl6.[rl_Indent4]
            AND rl7.[rl_Indent3] = rl6.[rl_Indent3]
            AND rl7.[rl_Indent2] = rl6.[rl_Indent2]
            AND rl7.[rl_Indent1] = rl6.[rl_Indent1] 
            AND rl7.[rl_Indent7] <> 0
            AND rl7.[rl_Indent8] = 0)           

        LEFT JOIN ReportingLevels rl8
            ON (rl8.[rl_CompanyID] = @CompanyID
            AND rl8.[rl_Indent7] = rl7.[rl_Indent7]
            AND rl8.[rl_Indent6] = rl7.[rl_Indent6]
            AND rl8.[rl_Indent5] = rl7.[rl_Indent5]
            AND rl8.[rl_Indent4] = rl7.[rl_Indent4]
            AND rl8.[rl_Indent3] = rl7.[rl_Indent3]
            AND rl8.[rl_Indent2] = rl7.[rl_Indent2]
            AND rl8.[rl_Indent1] = rl7.[rl_Indent1]
            AND rl8.[rl_Indent8] <> 0
            AND rl7.[rl_Indent9] = 0)

        LEFT JOIN ReportingLevels rl9
            ON (rl9.[rl_CompanyID] = @CompanyID
            AND rl9.[rl_Indent8] = rl8.[rl_Indent8]
            AND rl9.[rl_Indent7] = rl8.[rl_Indent7]
            AND rl9.[rl_Indent6] = rl8.[rl_Indent6]
            AND rl9.[rl_Indent5] = rl8.[rl_Indent5]
            AND rl9.[rl_Indent4] = rl8.[rl_Indent4]
            AND rl9.[rl_Indent3] = rl8.[rl_Indent3]
            AND rl9.[rl_Indent2] = rl8.[rl_Indent2]
            AND rl9.[rl_Indent1] = rl8.[rl_Indent1] 
            AND rl9.[rl_Indent9] <> 0
            AND rl9.[rl_Indent10] = 0)

    WHERE
        rl0.[rl_CompanyID] = @CompanyID
        AND rl0.[rl_Indent1] = 0);


INSERT INTO @result
SELECT * FROM @tmp1 
UNION 
SELECT * FROM @tmp2
ORDER BY [rl_DisplayName]

RETURN
END
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to use the syntax for a inline table-valued function when you actually have a multi-statement table-valued function. See the full description [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186755.aspx).

You're using this:

```
--Transact-SQL Inline Table-Valued Function Syntax 
CREATE FUNCTION [ schema_name. ] function_name ( [ { @parameter_name [ AS ] [ type_schema_name. ] parameter_data_type 
    [ =default ] [ READONLY ] } 
    [ ,...n ]
  ]
)
RETURNS TABLE
    [ WITH <function_option> [ ,...n ] ]
    [ AS ]
    RETURN [ ( ] select_stmt [ ) ]
[ ; ]
```

BUT, you really want this:

```
--Transact-SQL Multistatement Table-valued Function Syntax
CREATE FUNCTION [ schema_name. ] function_name ( [ { @parameter_name [ AS ] [ type_schema_name. ] parameter_data_type 
    [ =default ] [READONLY] } 
    [ ,...n ]
  ]
)
RETURNS @return_variable TABLE <table_type_definition>
    [ WITH <function_option> [ ,...n ] ]
    [ AS ]
    BEGIN 
        function_body 
        RETURN
    END
[ ; ]
```

Comment: It now says Select statements included within a function cannot return data to a client.
IS this not correct having this at the end SELECT * FROM @tmp1
UNION
SELECT * FROM @tmp2
ORDER BY [rl_DisplayName]
RETURN
END

Comment: You want to `INSERT INTO @return_variable SELECT * FROM @tmp1 UNION SELECT * FROM @tmp2 ORDER BY [rl_DisplayName] RETURN END`. It is the `@return_variable` that is used to pass your result set back to the caller.

Comment: when I alter now it says Cannot perform alter on 'dbo.udf_ReportingLevelStructure2' because it is an incompatible object type.

Comment: No idea why you'd get that message. Try to DROP and CREATE from scratch instead.

Comment: @Joe Stefanelli: the type field in sys.object changes from IF to TF = new object...

Answer (score 2):

To change function type you must have to drop function and then only you can change function type by creating new type function.

There are three types of functions.

- **Scalar**
- **Inline table valued**
- **Multi Statement**

ALTER cannot be used to change the function type.

**You need to DROP and CREATE the function**

Answer (score 0):

Your header syntax for inline table valued functions

```
...
RETURNS TABLE 
AS
RETURN 
(
    SELECT .. FROM something WHERE ...
)
GO --end of function
```

You have a multi-valued table function.

```
...
RETURNS @result TABLE
(
CompanyName VARCHAR(300),
[rl_Index] INT,
[rl_Addr1] VARCHAR(MAX),
[rl_Addr2] VARCHAR(MAX),
[rl_DisplayName] VARCHAR(MAX)
);
AS 
BEGIN
...
Do this

Do that

Data into @result 

END --of function
GO
```

[See MSDN for examples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191165.aspx)

Comment: It now says Select statements included within a function cannot return data to a client. IS this not correct having this at the end SELECT * FROM @tmp1 UNION SELECT * FROM @tmp2 ORDER BY [rl_DisplayName] RETURN END

Answer (score 0):

Just Drop and Create your SQL statement

[image]